# How to force IntelliJ IDEA to use the name of the jar-file specified in the gradle.build as artifact name?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have multi-project web application that configurable by Gradle. In one subproject  (let's call it 'XYZ') I specify desired jar-file name.

```
jar {
   archiveName 'archiveName.jar'
}
```

When I import this project into IntelliJ IDEA (File -> New -> Project from Existing Sources...), IntelliJ IDEA generate artifact description for WAR file. In this artifact description subproject JAR file in WEB-IBF/lib named as `<rootProject.name>-XYZ.jar`.

How to force IntelliJ IDEA to use the name of the jar-file specified in the gradle.build as artifact name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Delegate the build to Gradle](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2016/11/gradle-goodness-delegate-build-and-run.html) or [use Gradle tasks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-run-debug-configuration-for-gradle-tasks.html) to build the artifacts instead of IntelliJ IDEA. Vote for the [related request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160498).